# Replace text in multiple cells in a table on Microsoft Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a large table in Microsoft Word and I'm wanting to highlight a selection of cells in the last column and change the text in them from "Current" to "**Changed**". I know you can just use copy and paste or use a find/replace but I do this multiple times a day so it would be incredibly useful to just highlight and click a button.

I've got some VBA in Excel that works fine on spreadsheets but doesn't seem to work in Word.

```
Sub WordEdit()

    Dim x As Range
    For Each x In Selection
    If x.Value <> "" Then x.Value = "Changed"
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm not an expert in VBA so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried recording a macro and editing it? Have you used the Object Browser to look up the relevant objects, or used F1 to look things up in the documentation?

Comment: Tried recording a macro on Word but it was only editing the first cell of what I selected. Had a look on the documentation which is what I used to help create the above VBA but it doesn't seem to work on Word. Done countless google searches and looked on stack overflow but it all seems to be geared towards Excel and nothing I try seems to work for Word.

Comment: The macro recorder records everything using the Selection object. Then to generalize the code so it can work anywhere, you normally switch everything to the Range object. To find Word-specific VBA, add "Word" in quotation marks and -Excel (with a minus sign) to your search terms.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thanks I'll take a look at the Range object and see if I can get anywhere with that.

Comment: Recording a macro gives you the required syntax and a starting point for your research. Your recorded macro would have shown you that in Word you set the `Text` property, not `Value`. Looking up `Selection` in the Object Browser you would have found it contains a `Cells` collection. Selecting Help for `Cells` would take you to the Word VBA documentation where you would learn how to loop through the collection. As an IT consultant, you should be used to thinking through problems logically and using the available research tools.

Comment: You should change the title of your question to "Replace" text rather than "Insert" text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will change the word "Current" to "Changed" in the selection. Note, for this macro, you must have the words as part of the selection. It does not need to be in the last column, nor in a table; it does need to be in the selection.

```
Sub ChangeSelectionCurrentToChanged()
    ' Charles Kenyon 13 Oct 2020
    Dim rng As Range
    '
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Current"
        .Replacement.Text = "Changed"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

The following macro will change the word "Current" to "Changed" if it is in the last column of **any table** in a document. What is selected does not matter.

```
Sub ChangeCurrentToChanged()
    ' Charles Kenyon 13 Oct 2020
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iColumns As Long
    Dim iRows As Long
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim oTable As Table
    '
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Let iColumns = oTable.Columns.Count
        Let iRows = oTable.Rows.Count
        For iCount = 1 To iRows
            Set rng = oTable.Cell(iCount, iColumns).Range
            With rng.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = "Current"
                .Replacement.Text = "Changed"
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next iCount
    Next oTable
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set rng = nothing
End Sub
```

The following macro will change "Current" to "Changed" in the last column of the **current table** (the one where the insertion point is located).

```
Sub ChangeCurrentToChangedSelectedTable()
    ' Charles Kenyon 13 Oct 2020
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iColumns As Long
    Dim iRows As Long
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim oTable As Table
    '
    Set oTable = Selection.Tables(1)
        Let iColumns = oTable.Columns.Count
        Let iRows = oTable.Rows.Count
        For iCount = 1 To iRows
            Set rng = oTable.Cell(iCount, iColumns).Range
            With rng.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = "Current"
                .Replacement.Text = "Changed"
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next iCount
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Will one of these meet your needs?

Comment: The first one worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for that and the other suggestions which will help me improve my VBA skills for the future.

Comment: An excellent, although somewhat dated resource is the Word MVP site. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm

Comment: Just a note, I edited out the two lines from each macro that reset the Find.Text and Replacement.Text to "". Per advice from Word MVP Jay Freedman, those are not needed since we are working with a Range rather than the selection object.