# Find and replace text with an image in Word using VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having some trouble with this macro I am trying to create.
What I want to achieve is having a Source Word Document that contains a table with 2 columns, column 1 will hold the text I want to find within another document. In the 2nd column will either be an image or a file path to an image.

The macro script should open the source document, then run through the current document and find all the matching text and then replace that with the image.

This is what my script looks like currently:

```
Sub FindReplaceWithValuesFromTable()
    
    ' Open the document containing the replacement values
    Dim tblDoc As Document
    Set tblDoc = Documents.Open("C:\path\to\replacement_values.docx")
    
    ' Loop through each row in the table and perform the find and replace operation
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim findText As String
    Dim replaceText As String
    
    Set tbl = tblDoc.Tables(1)
    
    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        findText = tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text
        replaceText = tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
        
        ' Trim the find and replace text to remove any unwanted characters
        findText = Trim(findText)
        replaceText = Trim(replaceText)
        
        ' Perform the find and replace operation
        ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute findText, ReplaceWith:=replaceText, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next i
    
    ' Close the document containing the replacement values
    tblDoc.Close
    
End Sub
```

The script runs without an error but does absolutely nothing else.

I have tried removing all the formatting on both source and destination documents

I have tried using an image and then re-doing the script to allow for the image field

I have tried just replacing text with text.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the value of `tblDoc.Tables.Count` ? Is it what you would expect?

Comment: Hi braX, thanks for the feedback, I added the breakpoint and stepped through it step by step, however, I can see the source document open, it then goes to the next step, etc, but it doesn't find and replace even the simplest of text. What else do think I am doing wrong?

Comment: The source document only has one table in it, with 2 columns of data and currently only 3 rows of data

Comment: The end goal of this exercise is to find text in a document and replace it with an image. For example, if the text is "123 Lewis Lane" in the document I'm working on the Macro should find all instances of "123 Lewis Lane" and replace it with an image of the property, or a floor plan, etc. 
So within my document with the single table, in column 1 I would have "123 Lewis Lane" and in column 2 I would have either a picture or a file path to the picture.
I was having trouble having the Macro do what I want so simplified it to just look for text and replace it with text.

Hope that clears it up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337850/replace-text-in-multiple-cells-in-a-table-on-microsoft-word-using-vba

Comment: Thanks, I was sent down the rabbit hole with that link, I managed to make it work but in a completely different way. Thanks again

Comment: Usually it's down to the fact that Cell().Range.Text contains a 2-character end-of-cell marker in addition to the visible text, so you're not searching for what you hoped you were searching for.